# Problems with PFX certificate and AD DS account protection

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703

We have a certificate for code signing our .NET executables, and secure the private key with [AD DS account protection](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13922.certificate-pfx-export-and-import-using-ad-ds-account-protection.aspx). It works fine unless you use a Win 10 PC and updated to 1703 (creators update).

Here's an example command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\signtool.exe" sign /f "C:\code_signing_cert.pfx" -tr "http://timestamp.comodoca.com" "FileIWantToSign.exe"
```

With the **1703** update we get an error saying

```
The specified PFX password is not correct.
```

Any ideas? Do we need to change anything on the PCs/in the domain to make account protection work with 1703?

Comment: use signtool.exe from [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and not the 8.1 one.

Comment: Thanks @magicandre1981. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the issue. We tried multiple Win 10 SDKs including your linked one.